# Struts2 - Delaying an action execution

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, struts2

I have 2 different actions and I'm getting responses to those 2 actions at the same time, from the **same host**.

I want to delay one action for 30 seconds. 
I tried using `Thread.sleep(30000)` but, it seems to delay both the actions.

Both actions are background processes, hence I cannot use the **ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor**.

**Below is ths action that I want to delay.**

```
@Namespace(StrutsConstants.Namespace.PUBLIC)
public class CCAveDNHandlerAction extends  BaseRequestResponseAwareAction {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CCAveDNHandlerAction.class);

    public String execute() throws ModuleException {

        log.info("CCAveDNHandlerAction ### Starting..");

        try {               
            Thread.sleep(30000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Struts2 documentation says that 2 different requests are executed in 2 different threads.

But in this scenario it is not happening. May be because the 2 requests are coming from the same host. Is there a way to force an action to get executed in a **separate context** ?

Here is the work flow.

- User is redirected to an external payment gateway page.
- User make a   successful payment and redirected back to a predefined
  action in my   app.
- At the same time payment gateway sends another response to    another
  action of my app.(This is a secondary response)
- I use `Thread.sleep` for this action and the whole process is paused.
- I want to pause only the secondary response. **How can I do this?**

Comment: Could you post some parts of your code ?

Comment: What is the use case? How are you executing your actions?

Comment: @AleksandrM : The above code refers to an action that is used to process an server to server request. This is  used to persist payment confirmation.
The other action deals with the redirection from the payment gateway to my application's side.

Comment: Are you using Spring to manage the actions ? If yes, please post your conf

Comment: Can you describe step by step your workflow.

Comment: @AndreaLigios : I'm not using Spring to manage actions. I have updated the question. Since the 2 requests are coming from the same host, r they getting executed in the same session? Is there a way to force an action to get executed in a separate session ?

Comment: @AleksandrM : I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: And why do you want to delay action execution? It seems like you just need to handle pretty same case like double submit.

Comment: @AleksandrM : because both of the actions collides when updating the database. I must make sure one action is executed before the other starts executing. The secondary response is needed if the redirection to our side fails in any case.

Comment: Yes, standard procedure with payment systems. But think about it, it is the same case if double submit occurs. You don't need to delay actions, you need to handle persisting. It is done using session and checking in db whether object is already persisted or not.

Comment: @AleksandrM : It is not about simple persisting. The system is tracking status of payment and reservation. State transition conflicts occur. Struts2 documentation says that 2 different requests are executed in 2 different threads. But it is not happening here. why is that?

Comment: *State transition conflicts occur* what do you mean by that? How do you check it? Bottom line `Thread.sleep` won't solve your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75373/discussion-between-tharindu-dg-and-aleksandr-m).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Timer and do TimerTask definitions calling your actions. Then all you need to do is basically do a schedule for each timertask to be invoked and therefore invoke your action.

More on this in the javadoc@ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

GL

Comment: now as I think about it, you can also use two threads doing and waiting for each task separately, because obviously calling Thread.sleep() will suspend all actions done by the thread at the moment and AFAIK there's no way going around that...

Comment: Struts2 documentation says that 2 different requests are executed in 2 different threads. But in this scenario it is not happening. May be because 2 requests are coming from the same host. Is there a way to force an action to get executed in a separate context ?